# How do I use an Xbox One controller to play Mcpe on iOS?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, controllers

I've been searching mojang forums, nothing, videos online show this random controller, and some are on something different than iOS. Can somebody help me?

Here are some of the videos that I watched:

And

There obviously would be a way to do it, if not, why is the controller option there then?

Comment: Can you include a link to these videos?

Comment: Ok, I'll add a video

Comment: I would say that first video is your best bet.  However, that isn't an Xbox controller (at least not a standard one - and idk what kind of controller it is).  That may be an issue for an iOS device.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, I can't find an accurate video

Comment: I don't think you can do that with iOS. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bluetooth Support

First, you need to make sure that your Xbox One controller has Bluetooth support. The very early Xbox One controllers don't have Bluetooth support.

The easiest way to check if your controller has Bluetooth support is to check the bottom of the controller and see if it has a 3.5mm audio jack. If it does, then it has Bluetooth support. If it does not, you will have to get another controller.

[image]

All Xbox Series X|S controllers have Bluetooth support.

#### Updating the firmware of the Controller

Some controllers need a firmware update to enable Bluetooth support. I recommend checking the [Xbox support article](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/controller/update-xbox-wireless-controller) but here is the TLDR:

- Xbox One or Series X|S: Open the guide and then go to **Profile & system** > **Settings** > **Devices & connections** > **Accessories**. Select the Controller you want to update and press the 3 dots. If there is an update option, select it to update your controller. If the option is not present, your controller is up to date.
- Windows 10 or Windows 11: Download the [Xbox Accessories app](https://www.microsoft.com/p/xbox-accessories/9nblggh30xj3), open it with your controller connected via USB and it will tell you if there is an update available.

#### Connecting the controller to iOS

This is the easiest part. You will just have to follow the regular pairing process to get it connected to your phone.

I recommend reading Apple's support articles for [Connecting an Xbox controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211232) and [Pairing a Bluetooth accessory](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204091) but here is the TLDR:

To enter pairing mode, press the Xbox and then the Pair button for 3 seconds or until the Xbox button starts flashing. You then go to the Bluetooth options on iOS and it will appear there for pairing. Pair it as a regular Bluetooth device. After that the Xbox button will stop flashing.

#### Open the game

Minecraft Bedrock edition has support out of the box for controllers, so the game should automatically detect the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Bluetooth controller to connect it to your phone or tablet, most games aren't compatible with this setup though I believe Minecraft is.

Answer (score 0):

Press the small button on the top of your Xbox Controller, (It must be a wireless Controller) until the light on your controller starts flashing. This means that its now available to any other devices that are compatible with the controller. Once the light is flashing, open the settings app on your Ipad (or Iphone) then go to the Bluetooth tab. When you open the tab, look for a option that says, "Xbox Wireless Controller" then tap it. It should connect to your controller and the flashing will stop. When you open Minecraft, it should be ready to play with your controller. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

press the little button next to the bumpers in for 3 secs then go in to setting on iPhone go Bluetooth and it should be a device you can pair.

Answer (score -3):

I watched a video that said to press the small button to the right of the left bumper on the top of the controller. Currently, it’s not working for my iPad, but it might help.

Comment: I’m just gonna give up.